# How to OCR high number of images using azure vision without programming?

Tags: azure, ocr, microsoft

I have about 500 number of images that I definitely want to OCR these images with Microsoft azure vision.
**For some reason, I don't have any access to azure account at the moment.**
Can I OCR my images using Microsoft azure vision without programming and azure account?
for example I can use https://portal.vision.cognitive.azure.com/demo/extract-text-from-images but I must upload my images one by one and OCR them. I don't have enough time for this and I must do it automatically. **I even tried `OneNote` for this but it not good for numerical values and only good for letter values.**
If have any idea for this, please provide here.
Note that I'm not a programmer.
Please don't suggest me to use another OCR services, I want use Microsoft azure vision only for this.
Even If there are intermediary service that use Microsoft azure vision please share with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> without programming and azure account

Without account you can't use Azure service.

> want use Microsoft azure vision only

Create account, add your bank card and go.

Comment: I don't have access to my bank card at now. are there any way to create azure account without bank card?

Comment: @abolfazljoghori, you can create account w/o card. But I am not sure you can use any server w/o card.

Comment: does azure vision need credit on azure account or it is free?

Comment: @abolfazljoghori, for OCR you need 1$/1000 transactions: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/computer-vision/#pricing

Comment: can i use free trial credit for it?

Comment: @abolfazljoghori, AFAIK no

Comment: oh, no, this is a big problem